# Audio streaming server for large files with JAVA

Tags: java, android, audio, server, streaming

I have spent a couple of days googling but everything is a little bit too confusing, so I hope some of you can provide some general guidance.

In essence, I want to build a java server which would stream large audio files (let's say audiobooks) to android devices (native solution, not a web interface/player/etc).

Because I have zero experience with audio streaming it will take a while and I don't even know what practices could be considered "standard" - I checked some server applications like subsonic (and booksonic), considered streaming through REST (over HTTP by deviding files in chunks) but I am still lost.

What would be some of the best practices in a scenario where a native android application gets a list of streams from the server and can listen to audio without downloading it all?

I need it to be scalable and sustainable. It doesn't have to be Java based but it is preferred. I hope  you can shed some light. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html

Answer (score 0):

Media streaming (audio or video) is quite a specified area and it is often best to try to leverage open source streaming solutions rather than build your own solution from scratch.

There are several well known general purpose streaming solutions, such as GStreamer (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org) or icecast (http://icecast.org) many of which will have some form of binds to Java if you need to integrate like this - you often do not need to if you are integrating the streaming server as a standalone component into your architecture.